# Error in Libfreenect2 for Kinectv2

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-16.04, kinect-v2, libfreenect2

I'm trying to use `libfreenect2` in python 3.6 for getting the depth matrix of the Kinectv2. But there's an error. Take a look at the code.

```
import freenect2
import cv2

import numpy as np

"""
Grabs a depth map from the Kinect sensor and creates an image from it.
"""


def getDepthMap():

      depth, timestamp = freenect2.get_depth()

      np.clip(depth, 0, 2**10 - 1, depth)
      depth >>= 2
      depth = depth.astype(np.uint8)

      return depth

while True:
      depth = getDepthMap()

      blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(depth, (5, 5), 0)

      cv2.imshow('image', blur)
      cv2.waitKey(10)
```

Error - 
    `module 'freenect2' has no attribute 'get_depth'`

Comment: Does output of `import freenect2` and then `dir(freenect2)` print on your Python shell include `get_depth`?

Comment: Yeah, I got this -  `>>> dir(freenect2)
['__doc__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__'] `